# UITableview Flickering in ios 11 while working correctly in iOS 10.2

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, ios10.2, ios11.3

I am trying to update my cell size when I click on particular cell.My table gets update perfectly in iOS 10.2 but my table flickers when I run my code on iOS 11 .I am also getting warning in iOS 11 that 
`-[UIApplication application state] must be used from main thread.` 
So, I have reload my table in dispatch queue but nothing happens. I have multi-level XIBs like I have cell in which I have a table which is registering another cell which expands on click.
Below is my code sample when height expands my main table flicker.

```
func expandMessageTable(height : CGFloat,expendedRow:Int){

self.expandMessageHeight = height

self.msgExpRow = expendedRow

let row = cellMenuArr.index(of:"MessageXIB")

let path = IndexPath(row: row!, section: 0)
print(path)

homeTblView.reloadRows(at: [path], with: .fade)


}
```

Comment: When actually it flickers . When you reload it ? Don't reload the complete table just reload the updated cells.

Comment: When I reloading particular row at index path.

Comment: Can you show us the code that causes the problem?

Comment: you need to provide a code sample that reproduces the flickering. For the other issue, you are calling UIApplication.shared.applicationState from a background thread. Dispatch it on the main thread using DispatchQueue.main.async { (...)  }

Comment: I have updated my query just have a look. I am using cell XIB. and I have only one section in that table.

Comment: Just read my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the fine working code i am using to reload cells -

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                                self.tableView?.beginUpdates()
                                let contentOffset = self.tableView?.contentOffset
                                self.tableView?.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: j, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                                self.tableView?.setContentOffset(contentOffset!, animated: false)
                                self.tableView?.endUpdates()
                            }
                        })
```

Hope it helps.